# Java code error

Tags: java, operations-research

I'm not a good with java and trying to get implementation from it. I'm running [this code](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/65reductions/Simplex.java.html), but I got a lot of errors. Main error in

> StdOut cannot be resolved

Comment: "cannot be resolved" usually means you are trying to use a reference variable you haven't declared/instantiated yet.

Comment: Please post the code here.

Comment: You are either missing the class StdOut, or you are missing the JAR file that containst that class. The same goes for StdRandom.

Comment: Use `System.out` instead of `StdOut`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `StdOut` with `System.out`, or add this in the class:

```
OutputStream StdOut = System.out;
```

Comment: Thanks, This helps me. I got one more error in:
for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            c[j] = StdRandom.uniform(1000);
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
            b[i] = StdRandom.uniform(1000);
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                A[i][j] = StdRandom.uniform(100);
        Simplex lp = new Simplex(A, b, c);
        System.out.println(lp.value());
    }
Error in StdRandom

Comment: @user3688368 That's a new question, ask it seperately.

Comment: same thing you as this example. you need to import your random class

Answer (score 0):

Like Anubian said, use `System.out`

Or simply compile this, and place it with your `Simplex.java` Class file

Got this from the [Princeton repository](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdOut.java).

Answer (score 0):

StdOut is not declared in the scope. You may be missing an include. The best fix if you are using the Java API is to replace "StdOut" with "System.out". Also be sure to include java.lang.System.

Answer (score 0):

This class is in stdlib.jar .  you need to include that jar in your class path to remove these errors. Unfortunatly thic class StdOut does not have package declaration So you can not import it.

You have to create you class in default package to use this class.

I will suggest to use some other output stream.